# Keep short history of user display names

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, display-names, information-display

It'd be nice if each user's profile page showed what previous names that user had recently used.

Comment: Relatable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518

Comment: It should be noted that [moderators already have this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53323/does-stack-overflow-track-my-display-name-history). So the functionality is around, but not for all users.

Comment: I would not like my full name, which I used until a long time ago, to be visible to everyone again. (Related: [Make the “past names” list public info… At least temporarily](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-at-least-temporarily).)

Comment: How the fark is this "status completed"?!!  Moderators already had this info and the perp should know what aliases he's already "burned". (All this current "feature" does is aid shenanigans.)       This name information needs to be public.  **This is not status completed!**

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes, this would be very useful.  Sometimes looking at past comments can be confusing because people put in @ username_that_no_longer_exists.

Someone *really* needs to remove that "status-completed" tag.

Comment: Since they decided only moderators should have this feature, the question should be edited to reflect that the request was only for moderators.  Otherwise the "status-completed" tag is misleading.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [Make the "past names" list public info for 30 days after changing your name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-for-30-days-after-changing-your-name) which has more useful answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "recent names: 1" text appears next to the "Display name" field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346440/282094) - Removal [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347471/282094), and partial reimplementation [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361190/282094) - not on the Roadmap and not planned (February 2020). Recent duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312507/282094

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a tab in the Profile for 'Name History'.

Comment: If ever implemented: only for recent name changes please (so: only visible for a few days or weeks at most). I like the idea that I could change my real name (well, one never knows of course) into some alias one day. (For the same reason, I'd never use someone else's full name in replies. Like in references I prefer @Lance over the full name. And the recently introduced comment-alert works fine with that too.)

Comment: Agreed. It could even just go into the user's activity feed--that'd probably make implementation easier, too.

Answer (score 11):

We do have this information, and we can expose it. But the user page is quite busy already and needs a redesign, so I am not sure exactly when we will get to that.

Comment: Currently, there is no tooltip on user names in the user details below each post. If the user has changed names in the last 30 days (say), the tooltip could show "formerly known as ...". In both cases (tooltip or user page), you'd have to have a *suspicion* that something had changed to think to check, I'm not sure that there's a solution to that though [given the apparent Eek! factor of red ovals with 'new' in them :)]

Comment: Let's just go back to 1999 and put eyeglasses next to people with new names

Comment: I would not like my full name, which I used until a long time ago, to be visible to everyone again. (Related: [Make the “past names” list public info… At least temporarily](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-at-least-temporarily).)