# Is there a moderator "scorecard" I can use to identify people?

Tags: support, moderators

In the spirit of the old baseball adage "You can't tell the players without a scorecard," I'm wondering if there is anywhere that I can easily find out who the moderators on a site are -- not just their usernames, but who they are.  Actually, I'd settle for being able to know who a meta moderator is on SO.  Some people tend to change their names on meta and it's hard to always keep track of who is who.  That's ok for normal users or, at least, I don't care that much.  I would like to be able to easily know, for instance, that `Won't ಠ_ಠ` is actually `Will.`  I think I used to do this by looking at their Accounts page in their profile, but that only lists what accounts are associated now.  I have to actually click away to the other site to see their name there.

Comment: Won't is will? Didn't know it!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what "not just their usernames, but who they are" means -- what info exactly are you looking for if not their username?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ - sometimes it helps if you know who are interacting with.  People have personalities and communication styles.  One person might not get or misunderstand a joke or reference that another person might immediately pick up on.  I'm not here often enough to know what moniker someone has adopted and knowing which moderator I'm talking to would be helpful sometimes.

Comment: @Michael - basically the stuff that I would get from their profile, but like a "scorecard" it has all the players listed in one place making it easier to find them.  As I noted, my immediate interest is being able to keep track of a mods online identity when they change their moniker on meta.  Typically they don't on SO.

Comment: @Michael - easier to understand if you assume that the SO name is their moniker and, sometimes, they use a pseudonym on meta.  I'd like to know their actual moniker.

Comment: @tvanfosson Ok, so this is a meta-specific thing?

Comment: @Michael - for me, yes.  I was assuming that if something like that existed it would be for all the sites.  I suppose if it doesn't exist I'll have to change this from a `support` request to a `feature-request.`

Comment: @tvanfosson Well, I'm not sure how it makes sense anywhere else; MSO is the only place that has mods from other sites with potentially different names. Individual site metas only have the mods for that site, and names can't be different from the parent site

Comment: @Michael - at one point I remember there was page that listed all the moderators.  I suppose it could have been on the blog.  I was looking for that page and couldn't find it via the user interface.  My particular use case is only applicable to meta, but I seemed to recall that there was a place where all mods were listed.  Perhaps the feature doesn't exist.

Comment: related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28924/keep-short-history-of-user-display-names

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Excepting Shog9

Comment: tvan, If you have need for a page that simply lists all active moderators on a specific site, that's always at `/about`. It doesn't list the extra point of usernames on other sites, though.

Comment: The about page on all sites will list the mods: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @Grace - now I'm really confused.  There are a lot more ♦ users on meta than there are meta moderators.

Comment: Anyone who isn't listed as a meta moderator is a Stack Exchange employee, generally. I don't think there's any exception to this.

Comment: Why is everybody always up in my bidnez?

Comment: @won't - i just don't want to make you mad by mistake.  I'd rather do it on purpose. :-)