# How do I see my previous user names?

Tags: support, display-names

After changing my user name, how do I see my previous user names?

After GDPR, social networks have a data access tool where the user can see the previous user names and even biography texts and display name texts.

Is the same possible on Stack Exchange Network?

Comment: I don't think they are kept, your name is not how the system tracks you AFAIK. You are tracked by your ID 379894 and the name is just a bit of flair.

Comment: As for GDPR, there is option somewhere to download all your data, doesn't it contain your past names? I didn't try downloading it yet so can't really know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure. On some social networks out there, the user data archive contains the username history, on others it does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see your past names only up to 90 days, not before. In case you changed name in the past 90 days, go to your [Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) page, there you'll see "recent names" link below the Display Name field:

> [image]

Click the number, and you'll see your recent names and when they were last used:

> [image]