# The "recent names: 1" text appears next to the "Display name" field

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, display-names

I see the `"recent names: 1"` text on the "Edit profile and settings" page and I presume it's not something intended. It doesn't appear on all sites, but only the ones I recently joined<sup>[1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/),[2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)</sup>.

[image: recent names]

OS: Windows 10, Browser: Chrome 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was intended (it has actually been there for five years, displaying for any user whose display name changed recently). However, the feature itself is no longer necessary, and has been removed.

For moderators: if a user has changed their display name recently, you will still be able to see this and their recent names in the `Account Info` dropdown on their profile that you have access to.

Comment: Congrats on 20k Yaakov!

Comment: Uh. Just curious: why has it been removed?

Comment: yeah. As someone who changes her username from time to time (long story), the recent names list was the only indicator of when I could change it again. I'd argue it shouldn't be shown when a user first joins a site (because that's a thing for some reason), but should show after an intentional username change

Comment: I strongly disagree it's "no longer necessary" - it was useful information. The most useful part was what Zoe said, to know when I can change again, so I'll post a new feature request just for this.

Comment: Did you only know when you can change again? Or the actual history was important?