# Let us know when we can change display name again

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, display-names, profile-edit

Once upon a time, we could see recently used (90 days back) display names, then according to this, to know when we can change again, in case 30 days didn't yet pass since last used name.

However, this feature [was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347471/377214).

Instead of asking to bring back the past names, I suggest something different: in case we can't change the display name on a site, have the field disabled, with a lock icon, and show in a tooltip when we can change again:

> [image: mockup of requested change to display name]

Can this please be done? Currently the only way to know is to try changing the name, submit, then see the error message. Not very elegant.

Comment: As far as I can best tell, the user there was reporting that the old "recent names" button was mistakenly showing up when it wasn't supposed to (they had recently joined a site), but the developer handling the report mistook the report as "it is appearing *at all*", and so removed it.

Comment: @Sonic it's more like a case of a "bonus feature" that was never official aka part of original design becoming a hassle and removed when they realized it's not worth keeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion. Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future.

Comment: Thanks. Can't say I'm happy with the decision, but thanks for the update.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding. We're doing our best to stay focused on current commitments and following through on them.